# Withdrawing Bitcoin from Cryptsy

Tags: cryptsy

Does anyone think Cryptsy is ready to fold...I can't seem to withdraw anything for a while and their support team just give standard responses that are unhelpful. If they do go bust with peoples investment is there any way to get your coins back.....any answers appreciated thanks.

Comment: You could always move it to a wallet that you control. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_set_up_a_secure_offline_savings_wallet (assuming Cryptsy lets you withdraw bitcoins like this)

Answer (score 2):

Since starting cryptsy was one website I never trusted because of delayed credit and debit of coins and second thing their response team respond ticket in very unofficial manner. All you can do is put a withdraw request and wait for 24 hours may be another 24 hours.